# How to get current rendered element in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to change rendering of cell based on the element position, without changing data,
In docs I found `mData` and `mRender` options, I tried with `fnRender` (which is depricated), but it gives me position, but changes data in table while rendering, so I wonder if here is any way to get the cell position when it renders, or I should to rerender table myself after each change ?

the following code illustrate my needs:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [ {
      "aTargets": ['_all'],
      "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) 
      {
        if (type!='display') return data;
        //HOW to get current cell indexes or DOM element here ?
        console.log(this,data,type,full);
        return data+' ttt';
      }
    } ]
  } );

  $('#example > tbody > tr').on('click','td',function() {
   console.log(this);
   var pos=oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
   var value=oTable.fnGetData(this);
   oTable.fnUpdate(value.split("").reverse().join(""),pos[0],pos[2]);
  });


  var button=$('<button>').text('clickme');
  button.click(function() { console.log(oTable.fnGetData());});
  $('body').append(button);
});
```

http://live.datatables.net/enirid/3/edit

the sample using fnRender:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [ {
      "aTargets": ['_all'],
      "fnRender": function ( obj, data ) 
      {
        console.log(obj,data);
        var col=obj.iDataColumn;
        //HOW to change display here without changing data of table
        return data+' '+col;
      }
    } ]
  } );


   $('#example > tbody > tr').on('click','td',function() {
   console.log(this);
   var pos=oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
   var value=oTable.fnGetData(this);
   oTable.fnUpdate(value.split("").reverse().join(""),pos[0],pos[2]);
  });


  var button=$('<button>').text('clickme');
  button.click(function() { console.log(oTable.fnGetData());});
  $('body').append(button);
});
```

http://live.datatables.net/opubaj/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try [`fnCreatedCell`](http://datatables.net/ref#fnCreatedCell).
Attached the example code snippet provided from datatables.net:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [ {
      "aTargets": [3],
      "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
        if ( sData == "1.7" ) {
          $(nTd).css('color', 'blue')
        }
      }
    } ]
  });
} );
```

Comment: that event also need to be used after `fnUpdate` , I will update question now, and I need to change cell text, not cell class